# SSL with no-ip and XAMPP Apache server

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp, ssl-certificate, noip

I am working on a web page, and so that the clients could test it I mounted it on an apache server with xampp (windows). Also, I changed the ip to a domain at [www.no-ip.com](http://www.no-ip.com) and now it looks something like "example.ddns.net". The problem I have now is that I want to install an SSL certificate so that the non-secure page message won't appear, but I can't do it. I tried using https://zerossl.com/ which creates 3 files: "private.key", "certificate.crt" and "ca_bundle.crt". I have tried all the tutorials on the internet, seen all the videos on youtube but I can't find the solution. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: *"I have tried all the tutorials on the internet, seen all the videos on youtube but I can't find the solution."* - sorry, you basically exhausted already all available options. There is nothing more which we can recommend, which you didn't already try based on your own description.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, although I still hope that someone who had the same problem can give me the blog / tutorial he used. But Steffen, do you know if what I'm doing is possible or not? Maybe you can't even put SSL to a "no-ip" address and I'm trying something impossible to make.

Comment: You need to get a certificate for the domain name used to access the site, i.e. the name in the URL. If you would provide details of what you actually trying in detail one might maybe point out specific problems and solutions. But so far you basically state "it does not work" and it is not clear if you've setup the certificates incorrectly in the server, got certificates for the wrong domain or used the wrong name in the URL to access the site.

Answer (score 0):

They have actually added earlier this year free SSL certificate for their dynamic domains.

[SSL Certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQqET.png)

Check the following links for details on how to generate them.

1. First generate the CSR file
   https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/apache-openssl/
2. Then, follow the "second part" of the guide where you will add the CSR content to you domain in order for the SSL certificate to be generated.
   https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/get-trustcor-premium-dv-ssl/
3. The last part is to install the certificate to Apache. The installation is pretty much the same with all other SSL certificates (https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10026/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-xampp/).